# Spring Batch JpaPagingItemReader has no EntityManager in tests (NPE)

Tags: java, jpa, spring-batch, h2

I have a small Spring Batch job using `JpaPagingItemReader`. The job works well when I launch from command line but when I want to test `@StepScope` component `JpaPagingItemReader` I get a `NullPointerException`. I dont understand why the job works well but I can't test it as per documentation.

I have only one simple `Employee` class with basic `JPA`annotations.

Here is my job configuration class:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class PaySalaryJobConfiguration {

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public PaySalaryJobConfiguration(
            JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
            StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory
    ) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> employeeProcessor() {
        return item -> {
            log.info("Process item: {}", item);
            return item;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JpaPagingItemReader<Employee> someoneReader(
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("someone-reader")
                .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
                .queryString("Select e from Employee e order by e.id asc")
                .pageSize(1)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> csvWriter(
            @Value("#{jobParameters['output.path.csv']}") String outputPath
    ) {
        DelimitedLineAggregator<Employee> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");

        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Employee> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[]{"id", "firstName", "lastName", "salary"});
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);

        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("csv-salary-writer")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(outputPath))
                .lineAggregator(lineAggregator)
                .encoding("UTF-8")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step writeSalarySlipToCsv (
            JpaPagingItemReader<Employee> someoneReader,
            FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> csvWriter
    ) {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("retrieve-salary-slip-step")
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(1)
                .reader(someoneReader)
                .processor(employeeProcessor())
                .writer(csvWriter)
                .stream(someoneReader)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job paySalaryJob(
            Step writeSalarySlipToCsv
    ) {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("pay-salary-job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(writeSalarySlipToCsv)
                .build();
    }
}
```

And here is my test class:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBatchTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = PaySalaryJobConfiguration.class)
public class StepScopeIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private JpaPagingItemReader<Employee> someoneReader;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        log.info("Before execution we have {} entries", jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE", Integer.class ));
    }

    public StepExecution getStepExecution() {
        log.info("Step Execution !");
        StepExecution stepExecution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution("retrieve-salary-slip-step", 1564L);
        log.info("Context = {} / Step = {} ", stepExecution.getExecutionContext(), stepExecution.getStepName());
        return stepExecution;
    }

    @Test
    public void testReader() throws Exception {
        log.info("Page = {}", someoneReader.getPage());
        log.info("PageSize = {}", someoneReader.getPageSize());
        Assert.assertNotNull(someoneReader.read());
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in the `JpaPagingItemReader` class on line 192:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void doReadPage() {

    EntityTransaction tx = null;

    if (transacted) {
        tx = entityManager.getTransaction(); // EntityManager is null...
        tx.begin();

        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }//end if
```

And here is the stacktrace from test execution:

> 2019-06-12 17:17:32.845 - INFO  - [   main ] {
>   b.g.t.StepScopeIntegrationTest 45 } --> Step Execution ! 2019-06-12
>   17:17:32.845 - INFO  - [   main ] { b.g.t.StepScopeIntegrationTest 47
>   } --> Context = {} / Step = retrieve-salary-slip-step  2019-06-12
>   17:17:32.970 - INFO  - [   main ] { b.g.t.StepScopeIntegrationTest 41
>   } --> Before execution we have 4 entries 2019-06-12 17:17:33.002 -
>   INFO  - [   main ] { b.g.t.StepScopeIntegrationTest 53 } --> Page = 0
>   2019-06-12 17:17:33.002 - INFO  - [   main ] {
>   b.g.t.StepScopeIntegrationTest 54 } --> PageSize = 1
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JpaPagingItemReader.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ebb633d0.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b998315d.read()
>     at
>   be.groups.test.StepScopeIntegrationTest.testReader(StepScopeIntegrationTest.java:55)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

I'm using a h2 database and I fill my database with data on startup provided by an import.sql and an schema-h2.sql scripts. I'm working with Spring-Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE and Spring Batch Core 4.1.2.RELEASE.

Comment: Looks like the `EntityManagerFactory` is not being correctly setup in your test class (hence it is not injected in the reader). Are you sure the JPA config is loaded by spring boot? Can you try to add `@SpringBootTest` ? Two side notes: 1. I don't see why your reader should be step scoped and 2. The reader should be opened before calling `read` in your test method to honor the `ItemStream` contract.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine thank a lot ! 1) you are right, reader doesn't have to be scoped. 2) I've tested by calling `ItemReader.open()` first and it works now. Maybe you could add this point in the documentation ? At the moment in the documentation we have a simple example of a test on `ItemReader´ that doesn't need to call open() method...

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. In regards to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/testing.html#testing-step-scoped-components), there is a code comment saying "the reader is initialized", I think ithis refers to the `open` method. However, not all readers implement `ItemStream` and one could call `read` directly for those readers. In your case, the `JpaPagingItemReader` is an item stream and that's why it needs to be opened/initialized before being used to read data. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised by Mahmoud Ben Hassine in comments, I've changed my test class to:

```
@Slf4j
//@SpringBootTest
@SpringBatchTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        PaySalaryJobConfiguration.class
})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class StepScopeIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private JpaPagingItemReader<Employee> someoneReader;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        log.info("Before execution we have {} entries", jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE", Integer.class ));
    }

    public StepExecution getStepExecution() {
        log.info("Step Execution !");
        stepExecution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        log.info("Context = {} / Step = {} ", stepExecution.getExecutionContext(), stepExecution.getStepName());
        return stepExecution;
    }

    @Test
    public void testReader() throws Exception {
        log.info("Page = {}", someoneReader.getPage());
        log.info("PageSize = {}", someoneReader.getPageSize());
        someoneReader.open(stepExecution.getExecutionContext());
        Assert.assertNotNull(someoneReader.read());
    }
}
```

And the test work well now.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. You would have had the same issue outside the test scope. As commented in this JIRA bug, you need to define the bean to return an ItemStreamReader object instead of the JpaPagingItemReader.

Here is the original comment from Jimmy Praet

> The open() method of your writer hasn't been called because the writer
>   isn't registered as a stream. Your bean definition method should
>   return an ItemStreamReader instead of ItemReader so it gets registered
>   as a stream automatically.

Here is the reference
https://jira.spring.io/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/BATCH-2256/BATCH-2256.html